# How can I select a particular subdivided surface (the mini square inside the cube) after the subdivision surface modifier has been applied?

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image][image]I want to delete a particular subdivided surface to create a cavity. I'm in edit mode, chose the face select mode. I tried to zoom in to the subdivided object inside the cube, but I could only select the face of the external cube.

Comment: Hello, could you please show a screenshot? Are you sure that the modifier has been applied?

Comment: Hi @moonboots thank you for helping out! I just added a screenshot. I think I added the modifier.

Comment: @moonboots It hasn't been applied according to that image!

Comment: @Meeegandaily You may have added the modifier, but you need to Apply it before you can select individual faces! Hover over the modifier panel in Object mode so that the modifier has a blue outline and use Ctrl-A to apply it.

Comment: Thank you @JohnEason I tried but I couldn't figure it out. I updated a screenshot, is the right-hand side the modifier panel? What should I do with that sorry I'm a super dummy

Comment: As John says, put your mouse over the modifier and press Ctrl A (or click on the down arrow on the top of the modifier and click on Apply). Now your topology will be real, not virtual (but you'll lose the benefits of a modifier of course)

Comment: omg it worked! thanks both!

Comment: For future reference, you'll see that there is a very thin blue line round the modifier panel in your added image. That means that it's selected and you can apply it. If you had more than one modifier there you could click anywhere inside the panel of the modifier that you want to apply, hover the mouse over it, and then hit Ctrl-A (or use the modifiers dropdown as @Moonboots says).

Comment: @JohnEason You're so nice! Thank you so much I'll keep that in mind thanks for the lesson!